# Plax.js does not activate in time

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've been trying using jQuery plugins before and it never worked. Yesterday I tried to use a plugin called plax: https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax

I thought I got everything right but it didn't work. Maybe it's because of the jQuery library version? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should use the library used in the demo pages? jQuery 1.6?

Comment: What are you doing wrong?  How are we supposed to know when you have not shown anything that you've done?

Comment: Okay I am going to make an example page trying to do that. I'll send you a link.

Comment: Yes, but don't just post a link, you must include the code within the OP as well.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done here it is: http://www.gameplay-universe.tk/plax.php

Comment: plax.js is HTML, not JavaScript

Comment: It is JavaScript, I changed that.

Comment: Now that you have there are errors in the console. You need to fix those.

Comment: Have you tried it with the latest stable jQuery instead of using the developer version you've linked?  Is Plax.js actually where your link is looking for it (in the root of your site)?  What exactly "doesn't work", what happens when you try the code you've supplied?

Comment: You mean "TypeError: layers[0] is undefined"? That doesn't appear to be my problem it is the plugin's problem.

Comment: @PowerUser, if you have ANY errors in the console, they can likely mess up any successive code.  So the first error is the one you need to concern yourself with.  Don't assume that the plugin is at fault.  And if it truly is the plugin that's at fault, you need to fix it or use another plugin.  I see a problem with your code, though I don't know if this will fix the problem - you cannot refer to elements in Javascript/jQuery before they exist on the page.  So your code beginning at `$('#img1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})` , #img1 does not exist yet.

Comment: @techie007 See http://www.gameplay-universe.tk/plax.php
Yes it is there. And the images do not move. What I wanted was just to have a GitHub-style page - see this: https://github.com/agsadgdsgfdg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your example page, maybe it's because you aren't waiting for the document to be ready.
change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#img1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
$('#img2').plaxify({"xRange":10,"yRange":10,"invert":true})
$.plax.enable()
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#img1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
$('#img2').plaxify({"xRange":10,"yRange":10,"invert":true})
$.plax.enable()
});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! I could've never found out about that myself! Wow thanks!